sudo segmentation fault
In a remote system to which I don't have console access, which I'm connecting through ssh, I broke the sudo installation and now I'm not able to use it at all, and I'm not able to restart as a root. The command I ran was:
sudo mv /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6_org

Everytime I do sudo <command or option> it says segmentation fault, for example:
~$ sudo -s
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

As specific cases,

id works: uid=1479554(s1474782) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),27(sudo),999(docker)
sh works as well
sudo id doesn't work: sudo id Segmentation fault (core dumped)
su s1474782 -c id doesn't work: sudo id Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I was updating some libraries and I think I broke the libm.so.6 library, however I don't see sudo depending on it:
ldd $(which sudo)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd7ef9e000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007f139de21000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f139dbff000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f139d9fc000)
    libsudo_util.so.0 => /usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0 (0x00007f139d7e8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f139d41e000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f139d1ae000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f139cfaa000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f139e26b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f139cd8d000)


Any advice how to solve this? I can just re-install sudo?

Does su s1474782 -c id work? You'll need to use your password to test this, and I'm asusming your username is s1474782. (I'm looking to see if the problem lies in the PAM authentication subsystem or in sudo itself.

And for next time: do not update libraries in such way (especially standard library: libm is part of C standard library). And if you want to develop such libraries, you should  test on a container or/and have static linked toolset

Hi @ChrisDavies, su s1474782 -c id gives the same Segmentation fault (core dumped) error, I'll update the question

@GiacomoCatenazzi, you are right, I learnt it the hard way...
